# A separate partition for a user's /home directory?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, users, home, dm-crypt

I plan to encrypt a user's `/home` directory, prefering `dm-crypt` over  `eCryptfs`, which seems to read data x times faster. But encrypting the whole `/home` would be a problem for others, entering an encryption key at every login.

Is it possible to separate `/home/$USER` as a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out as that user, proceed as root. Create said additional partition with fdisk or parted. Make temporary mountpoint for that partition, say /mnt/tempuser. Mount it to that mountpoint. Rsync /home/$USER to /mnt/tempuser/ and then mv /home/$USER /home/originaluser. Mkdir /home/$USER and chown it to said $USER

Now try logging in as $USER. su - $USER from that same root console for example. Should be enough to test if it worked or what went wrong. Fallback would be

```
umount /home/$USER ; mv /home/$USER /home/faileduser ; mv /home/originaluser /home/$USER
```

Then if all seems fine with logging in like that, add it to /etc/fstab so it gets mounted on boot, define mountpoint here as /home/$USER

Comment: No worries, it was just for backup, not ultra-necessary. One could have mounted new partition also on top of existing directory and deleted content of old one later if all works well.